# Call to a member function on a non-object PHP

Tags: php, composer-php, stripe-payments, autoload

I am attempting to use Cartalyst, a comprehensive PHP Library for Stripe payments. Here is a link to their documentation: https://cartalyst.com/manual/stripe/1.0. Here is the code I am trying to get to work:

```
$stripe    = \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('your-stripe-api-key');
$customers = $stripe->customers()->all();

foreach ($customers['data'] as $customer) {
    var_dump($customer['email']);
}
```

When I run the code above (in my real code I have my api inserted), I receive the following error:

> Call to a member function customers() on a non-object in

Also, here is my composer code that is generating the autoload files:

```
{
    "require": {
        "cartalyst/stripe": "~1.0",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "3.*"
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the result of `var_dump($customers)`?

Comment: Do you have any costumers already ? Also, make sure you use `$stripe = new Stripe();` before any further queries.

Comment: @PedroLobito Yes, many customers are in our Stripe account.

Comment: @three3 only mark a question solved if the answer actually resolves your issue.  Based on what you're posting here, you've taken the original issue's answer which just moved the same problem to another line. :)  Let me take a look at your original question and see if I can find a better answer.

Comment: @Sean Thank you very much. I agree with you! But two people who were helping kept insisting that I post a new question before they would continue to help. If you read the comments on the original post, you will see what I am talking about. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: You can always EDIT a question you have if your commenters suggest you add more info. Now we have the correct question with your code that doesn't work, and the incorrect answer there, and this new question with incorrect code that came from the answer you accepted as "working". You can still unaccept that answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know `cartalyst/stripe`, but [Stripe::setApiKey](https://github.com/cartalyst/stripe/blob/1.0/src/Stripe.php#L119) isn't a static method. If you call `Stripe::setApiKey` in that way, it will return `NULL`.

Try, as the documentation suggest,

```
$stripe = \Cartalyst\Stripe\Stripe::make('your-stripe-api-key');

$customers = $stripe->customers()->all();

foreach ($customers['data'] as $customer) {
    var_dump($customer['email']);
}
```

Comment: I just tried your code and I received the following error message: `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Stripe\Stripe::make() in`. Any thoughts? Thanks for the help.

Comment: I am testing it now. Fingers crossed!

Comment: This solved my issue! Thank you very, very much! I wish this would have been in their documentation :)